# C# Text wraps after first word

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a problem. The text in my WPF app wraps after the first word. 
The odd thing about this is that it doesn't happen with the first created text or with any other texts I create the same way.

[image: Picture of the odd Wrapping]

I already tried to set Wrapping to Wrap, No Wrap and delete the option but nothing changed anything.

Here my code:

```
public partial class ConfigPage : Page
    {
        int hohe = 50;
        public ConfigPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < CarLoad.Autos.Length; i++)
            {
                TextBlock newTxt = new TextBlock();
                newTxt.Text = CarLoad.Autos[i].AutoInfos();
                newTxt.Name = "TxtBlockI" + i.ToString();
                newTxt.Width = 545;
                newTxt.Height = 20;
                newTxt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                newTxt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                newTxt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                newTxt.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial Black");
                newTxt.Margin = new Thickness(65, hohe, 0, 0);

                TextBlock newTxt2 = new TextBlock();
                newTxt2.Text = CarLoad.Autos[i].TankInfos();
                newTxt2.Name = "TxtBlockT" + i.ToString();
                newTxt2.Width = 545;
                newTxt2.Height = 20;
                newTxt2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                newTxt2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                newTxt2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                newTxt2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                newTxt2.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial Black");
                newTxt2.Margin = new Thickness(65, hohe + 20, 0, 0);

                TextBlock newTxt3 = new TextBlock();
                newTxt3.Text = CarLoad.Autos[i].SonstInfos();
                newTxt3.Name = "TxtBlockS" + i.ToString();
                newTxt3.Width = 545;
                newTxt3.Height = 20;
                newTxt3.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                newTxt3.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                newTxt3.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                newTxt3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                newTxt3.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial Black");
                newTxt3.Margin = new Thickness(65, hohe + 40, 0, 0);

                PackIcon icon = new PackIcon();
                icon.Kind = PackIconKind.CarSide;
                icon.Width = 50;
                icon.Height = 50;
                icon.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                icon.Margin = new Thickness(10, hohe, 0, 0);

                hohe = hohe + 60;

                gridn.Children.Add(newTxt);
                gridn.Children.Add(newTxt2);
                gridn.Children.Add(newTxt3);
                gridn.Children.Add(icon);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to address your problem directly. Instead I think it would be best to address your technique, since fixing the way you are going about this will probably resolve the problem anyway.

In WPF, an application is separated into "markup" (a.k.a. "UI" or "front-end") and "code-behind" (a.k.a "code" or "back-end"). The markup is written in XAML, and the code-behind is either C# or VB.NET. You link the two together using [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview). Common practice is to create most, if not all, of your UI in *markup*. You should *avoid* creating your UI via code-behind.

For your particular application, I would look into using an [`ItemsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol), which is a special control that "can be used to present a collection of items". It lets you declare your UI markup once, inside a [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview), and then reuses that template to show each item.

Here is an example based off your question, it probably isn't perfect, but it should be close to what you need:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CarLoad.Autos}" FontFamily="Arial Black" Foreground="White">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <local:PackIcon Grid.RowSpan="3" Kind="CarSide" Width="50" Height="50" Foreground="White" Margin="10"/>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding AutoInfos}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TankInfos}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SonstInfos}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Note also that I didn't arrange the elements using `Margin`, that is bad practice. `Margin` is for providing space between elements, but not for giving them an exactlocation. Instead, WPF has several controls that allow you to create dynamic layouts. In the example above, I used a [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid) control.

If you are unfamiliar with any of these terms or technologies, I'd suggest you read up on them, as they are the backbone of WPF.

Comment: Thanks, this did tidy up my code a lot :D But the probem is still there. Only the first one works.
My code for AutoInfos: 
`public string AutoInfos()
        {
            return "Marke: " + marke + ", Modell: " + modell + ", Farbe: " + farbe + ", PS: " + ps;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your example for some time and I'm going to take a stab at the direct answer, which has nothing to do with your posted C# code. Instead, I suspect that your `CarLoad.Autos[i].AutoInfos();` method returns a string containing a CR and/or LF after the text "Marke:" for all but the first element in the CarLoad.Autos array. Can you compare `CarLoad.Autos[0].AutoInfos();` with `CarLoad.Autos[1].AutoInfos();` in the debugger to determine if this is what is happening?

Comment: You're probably right. If `TextWrapping` isn't set anywhere, then there must be some line breaks somewhere in the string.